# Seting up a build for UWP in new dev.azure.com / TFS system

Tags: c#, tfs, uwp, continuous-integration

Followed the documentation Microsoft provides and are able to set up CI for my Application.

But I get like 129 error and its just an Initial commit..

```
MyFolder.Models\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(8,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssemblyTitleAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is an example of the errors I get.

This is the setup of my App:

Solution :

Models (Class library)

Services (Class library)

UWP application

Comment: Make sure you are using the "HostedVS2017" build agent

Comment: @MartinZikmund its default selected